# Terminate Async CGImageRef Load in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, asynchronous, grand-central-dispatch, uicollectionview

I have a collection view that kind of simulates cover flow.  It loads images asynchronously from the ALAssetLibrary like so.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    myCell *cell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CELL_ID" forIndexPath:indexPath];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0),
                       ^{
                           ALAsset *asset = [assets objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
                           CGImageRef thumbnailImageRef = [[asset defaultRepresentation]fullScreenImage];
                           UIImage *thumbnail = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:thumbnailImageRef];
                           dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                               cell.myImageView.image = thumbnail;
                           });
                       });

    return cell;
}
```

If the user scrolls quickly, the images take longer to load.  I'm thinking that, if the user quickly scrolls to image 20, they have to wait for images 1-19 to load even though they are no longer on screen.  So, my question is, is there a way to stop the image load if the cell moves off screen before the loading process is complete?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to cancel dispatch blocks once they have been queued. I have implemented something similar to this using an `NSOperationQueue`. Replace your dispatch calls with `NSOperation` subclasses that have a property identifying which index path they belong to, and put them in an operation queue. Then, during the scroll delegate callback, iterate over queue, cancelling operations that are too far away.

Comment: Could you post your implementation?